# enable vnc on xen without having to shut down all the domains

Tags: xen, vnc

The last guy forgot to enable vnc connections on our Xen blade and I need to install a windows domain, is there any way I can enable vnc without shutting down half our company?

From what I can tell I need to edit xend-config.sxp which would likely require a restart of xend, which means shutting down all the running domains. Is there any way around this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Core configuration change on the hyper-visor level requires a restart of the hyper-visor requiers.... an interruption of all instances running on the hyper-visor.